# Keep only a few x-axis labels for a qualitative variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, strftime

I am trying to plot a `data.table` with two columns : a `Date` column, and another quantitative variable. My quantitative variable has seasonal variations, but is not exactly the same throughout the years. My goal is to compare the evolution of this variable across different years.

Here is a dummy dataset :

```
library(tidyverse)

data=data.table(date=seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="day"),
                value=rep(seq(0.1, 36.6,0.1)),2)
```

I want to facet this ggplot by year. For that, I use `strftime` :

```
ggplot + 
   aes(x = strftime(Date,"%m-%d"), y=value,group="") +
   facet_wrap(~strftime(Date,"%Y"),,nrow=3) + 
   geom_line()
```

This works perfectly, but gives an ugly background and an unreadable x axis legend, since we have one legend + one graduation per day.

[image: The ugly graph]

I figured the graph would be more readable if I could keep only one legend label per month. Do someone know how to do that ?

## Edit

After @Gregor Thomas's edit and comment, I would like to stress that keeping the date format for the x axis and changing the axis format using `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 month")` (like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748384/formatting-dates-on-x-axis-in-ggplot2)) gives an plot that can not be interpreted :

[image: The useless graph]

It is worse in  my real dataset, since I have more than two years. The goal of `strftime` was to adress this problem.

## Edit 2 : a solution

I found a solution for this, using `scale_x_discrete` :

```
end_month=c(
  "01-31",
  "02-28",
  "03-31",
  "04-30",
  "05-31",
  "06-30",
  "07-31",
  "08-31",
  "09-30",
  "10-31",
  "11-30",
  "12-31"
)

ggplot + 
   aes(x = strftime(date,"%m-%d"), y=value,group="") +
   facet_wrap(~strftime(date,"%Y"),,nrow=3) + 
   geom_line() +
   scale_x_discrete(break=end_month)
```

This answers the question. However, I would be interested in another solution especially if I it is possible to keep the `Date` format
for the x axis while still keeping the facet aligned. The reason for that is that I have breaks in my time series and the `strftime` gives the impression that I have a continuous series.

Comment: Use `x = Date` not `x = strftime(Date,"%m-%d")`. ggplot knows how to handle `Date` class objects, but `strftime` converts to character. Add `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")`. See the `?scale_x_date` help page for more options, you might want to use  `date_labels` to select your label format.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, since this gives a plot that can not be used for analysis. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, this is much clearer about the issue now. The common way to compare time series across years is to make a dummy column where the dates all have the same year, and then facet or color by the true year. [See this answer, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803582/903061).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I have found a much simpler solution using `facet_wrap(scales = "free_x")`, that allows the three graphs to be aligned, since I have data for each day.